# Why there is no errors while multiplying floating point numbers?

Tags: c, floating-point

I need some clearification about floating point math.

I have wrote some code for the learning purpouses:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int i;
    double a=1.0/10.0;
    double sum=0;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        sum+=a;

    printf("%.17G\n", 10*a );
    printf("%d\n", (10*a == 1.0) );

    printf("%.17G\n", sum );
    printf("%d\n", (sum == 1.0) );

    return 0;
}
```

and the output it gives is:

```
    1
    1
    0.99999999999999989
    0
```

Why (sum == 1.0) - is false is pretty understandabale, but why multiplying gives the right answer without the error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When performing the repeated addition, there are 9 roundings taking place: the first result `a+a` is always exactly representable, but after that, further additions are inexact since the base-2 exponents of the addends are not equal.

When performing the multiplication, there's only a single rounding, and it happens to give you the result you wanted.

Comment: Actually, `a + a + a + a` is also always, barring overflow, exactly `4 * a` (this tidbit courtesy of Stephen Canon).

Comment: @PascalCuoq: No it's not. `(a+a)+(a+a)` would be exactly `4*a`. But floating point addition is not associative. The claim may be true in the default rounding mode (nearest/ties-to-even) by an argument about the roundings that happen, but it's certainly not true in general.

Comment: The remark is obviously in the context of a binary format specified by IEEE 754, with rounding to nearest even. If you are going to split hairs, your explanation assumes a binary format which nothing in the question justifies.

Comment: IEEE 754 has multiple rounding modes and specifies the behavior for all of them, so my objection to assuming the default one does make sense in that context. It should at least be noted that the behavior is dependent on rounding mode, since otherwise the claim *looks* obviously-wrong.

Comment: Re *and it happens to give you the result you wanted* -- that's key. On my computer, with default rounding, there are a number of numbers such that (1.0/x)*x is not equal to 1.0. (For example, x=49.0). It's best to treat floating point numbers as a somewhat crude approximation of the reals. Even an ideal Turing machine capable of infinite precision arithmetic has problems with the reals because almost all of the reals are not computable numbers.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the actual assembly language produced, you'll find that the compiler is not generating the single multiplication you're asking for. Instead, it's simply providing the actual value. If you turn off optimization you might get the results you're expecting (unless your compiler optimizes this anyway).

Comment: This would be an incorrect optimization, so the compiler should not be making it except in non-standards-conforming profiles...

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems with your code.

floating point on a computer is base 2.  You cannot represent 0.1 exactly in floating point (just like you cant represent 1/3rd in base 10 compared apples to apples), so any other assumptions after that (multiply by 10 and expect it to be a one for example) are bad.

The single multiply of 10 times 0.1 only incurs one times the error.  The multiple additions incur 10 times the error.  Rounding fixes the 10 times 0.1 when converting to integer making it look like it actually worked.  Rounding being yet another feature of IEEE floating point, the rounding mode used by default on your system as well as whatever the 1/10th became again basically made the single multiply look like it worked.

next problem is you are doing equals comparisons with floating point and I assume having some sort of expectation.  dont use equals on float, period.  Certainly not with numbers like this that cannot be represented exactly in floating point.

try a number like 1/16th for example or 1/8th instead of 1/10th...