# Is 3*x+x always exact?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

Assuming strict IEEE 754 (no excess precision) and round to nearest even mode, is `3*x+x` always == `4*x` (and thus exact in absence of overflow) and why?

I was not able to exhibit a counter-example, so I went into lengthy dicussion of every possible trailing bit pattern `abc` and rounding case, but I feel like I could have missed a case, and also missed a simpler demonstration...

I also have an intuition that this could be extended to `(2^n-1) x + x == 2^n x` and testing every combination of trailing bits in this case is not an option.

We should have `(2^n - 1) x == 2^n x - x` by property of IEEE 754 as long as n <= 54, but `y-x+x == y` is not generally true...

Comment: Speculation: does it work for cases when x is at the smallest number (+ and -) to 0?

Comment: I have my doubts about the computation being exact, for fractions that use all the bits.  Keep in mind that 4*x will leave the fraction unchanged, but 3*x may lose a low-order bit.

Comment: @Rob: it trivially works for those cases, because every operation involved is exact.  It’s more interesting for “full width” floating-point numbers, where some of the intermediate steps incur rounding, but the final result is exact anyway.

Comment: My proof is here: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5671002 (short story: case analysis on whether `3*x` is in the same binade as `4*x` or in the same binade as `2*x`). In the same thread Stephen alluded to a proof by case analysis on the last three bits of the significand of `x`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the following, math shown in `code format` is computed with IEEE 754 in round-to-nearest mode, and math not in code format is exact.

Let *p* be the number of bits in the significand.

Let *f* be the factor 2<sup>*n*</sup>-1 for a positive integer *n* and be exactly representable (*n* ≤ *p*).

Let U(*x*) be the ULP of *x*. For normal values, U(*x*) ≤ 2<sup>1-*p*</sup>*x*.

Let *t* be `f*x`. If `f*x` is subnormal, then it is exactly *fx*. If it is normal, then *t* = *fx*+*e* for some |*e*| ≤ ½U(*fx*) ≤ 2<sup>-*p*</sup>*x*. Note that if |*e*| is exactly half an ULP, then it must equal the lowest bit of *x* that is set (since otherwise *e* would have more than one bit set and could not be half of an ULP).

Substituting for *f*, *t* = (2<sup>n</sup>-1)*x*+*e*.

*t*+*x* = (2<sup>*n*</sup>-1)*x*+*e*+*x* = 2<sup>*n*</sup>*x*+*e*.

Consider `t+x`. By IEEE-754 requirements of round-to-nearest, this must be within ½ an ULP of *t*+*x*, which we know to be 2<sup>*n*</sup>*x*+*e*. Clearly 2<sup>*n*</sup>*x* is representable (barring overflow), and |*e*| ≤ ½U(*fx*) ≤ ½U(2<sup>*n*</sup>*x*). Therefore `t+x` must be 2<sup>*n*</sup>*x* unless |*e*| is exactly half an ULP and the low bit of *x*’s significand is odd (since an even low bit wins the tie and gives 2<sup>*n*</sup>*x*).

If *n* is 1, then *f* is 1, and *e* is 0. If 2 ≤ *n*, then |*e*| ≤ 1/4 U(2<sup>*n*</sup>*x*) < ½U(2<sup>*n*</sup>*x*). So a case where |*e*| is half an ULP and *x*’s low bit is odd does not occur.

Therefore `t+x` must be 2<sup>*n*</sup>*x*. (Overflow and NaN left as an exercise for the reader.)

Additionally, I tested exhaustively for IEEE-754 32-bit binary floating-point.

Comment: Interestingly, this value is also exact when computed as `x+x+x+x` (or `(x+x)+(x+x)` or `4*x`, but those are obvious and unsurprising).  It follows that most reasonable means of computing the quantity 5*x are also exact, but this does not hold for 6*x.

Comment: @StephenCanon Yes, (2^n+1)*x=2^n*x+x I wanted to answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21676955/floating-point-product-expansion-equivalence that there is more than 1 wayto sum x+x+x+... but there is surprisingly few, 8*x==6*x+2*x==7*x+x