# I knew that 0.1D+0.2D==0.30000000000000004D - why 0.1D+0.1D==0.2D?

Tags: java, floating-point, ieee-754

Neither 0.1d, 0.2d or 0.3d can be represented exactly in binary.

Why is `0.1D + 0.1D == 0.2D` true in Java?

**the 64-bit binary number is how to become 0.1,0.2,0.3?????Where is the code?**

Comment: That's not really a duplicate - the op seems to  already know that not all decimal numbers can be represented exactly by a double...

Comment: nearest_float(x)+nearest_float(x)=nearest_float(2*x) is allways true in IEEE 754 whatever the language. We can't explain why in a comment... Maybe the question was closed prematurely.

Comment: @aka.nice reopened if you want to add an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that `x` is the exact decimal.
`nearest_float(x)` is the conversion to floating point.
It rounds to nearest representable floating point value, tie to even.
`ulp(nearest_float(x))` is the unit of least precision of the floating point value (i.e. the value of smallest bit of significand).
`x + y` denotes the exact arithmetic operation, same for - * /.
`nearest_float(x)+nearest_float(y)` is the exact sum of float approximations.
`nearest_float(nearest_float(x)+nearest_float(y))` is the floating point operation.

Operation `nearest_float(x)+nearest_float(x)` is strictly equivalent to `nearest_float(x)*2`, and the operation `nearest_float(x)*2` is exact, except the rare case of floating point overflow: it's just a shift of the exponent, `nearest_float(2*nearest_float(x))=2*nearest_float(x)`..

We have this property: `abs(nearest_float(x)-x) <= ulp(nearest_float(x))/2`.

We can multiply both sides of inequality by 2: `abs(2*nearest_float(x)-2*x) <= ulp(2*nearest_float(x))/2`.

Most often, there is a single value in this interval, exceptionnally two values in case of exact tie, but the exact tie will be resolved same as for the case of x (only the exponent changed, not the significand). Near binade boundaries, there might be 2 floats in above interval too, but resolution will also be to the same significand.
Thus it means that `2*nearest_float(x)` is the right candidate for `nearest_float(2*x)`

So in any language based on IEEE 754 floating point, with round to nearest, tie to even rounding mode (the default mode), and correctly rounded literal values (meaning that 0.1 will effectively return the nearest float to 1/10) you'll have the property 0.3+0.3==0.6, 0.07+0.07==0.14,  3.14+3.14==6.28, x+x==2*x whatever the value of x.

More surprisignly, you even have more funny properties like this one [Is 3*x+x always exact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21690585/is-3xx-always-exact)

Comment: why I define double d = 0.2,and the value I see is 0.2,not 0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125.

Comment: You see 0.2 because Double.toString "rounds" the double. To see the exact value use a BigDecimal like in my example.

Comment: @成一丁 You have at most 2^64 different floating point values (in which many nans). It's a finite subset of Rational fractions. So many decimals will round to the same float. What you see is the SHORTEST decimal representation that would round to the same floating point value, not the exact fraction value.

Answer (score 1):

If you run:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(0.1d + 0.1d));
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(0.2d));
System.out.println(0.1d + 0.1d == 0.2d); //true
```

you'll see that both statements print `0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125`.

In other words, `0.1d + 0.1d == 0.2d` is true but neither is strictly equal to the decimal number 0.2.

On the other hand, the first two lines below don't print the same number and `0.1d + 0.1d + 0.1d == 0.3d` is false:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(0.1d + 0.1d + 0.1d));
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(0.3d));
System.out.println(0.1d + 0.1d + 0.1d == 0.3d); //false
```