# Interchangeability of IEEE 754 floating-point addition and multiplication

Tags: c++, floating-point, ieee-754, numerical-stability

Is the addition `x + x` interchangeable by the multiplication `2 * x` in *IEEE 754 (IEC 559) floating-point standard*, or more generally speaking is there any guarantee that `case_add` and `case_mul` *always* give exactly the same result?

```
#include <limits>

template <typename T>
T case_add(T x, size_t n)
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559, "invalid type");

    T result(x);

    for (size_t i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        result += x;
    }

    return result;
}

template <typename T>
T case_mul(T x, size_t n)
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559, "invalid type");

    return x * static_cast<T>(n);
}
```

Comment: Note that there seem to be many ways to sum n*x, but surprisingly so many are equivalent! This is somehow related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21690585/is-3xx-always-exact and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21676955/floating-point-product-expansion-equivalence

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is the addition `x + x` interchangeable by the multiplication `2 * x` in IEEE 754 (IEC 559) floating-point standard

Yes, since they are both mathematically identical, they will give the same result (since the result is exact in floating point).

> or more generally speaking is there any guarantee that case_add and case_mul always give exactly the same result?

Not generally, no. From what I can tell, it seems to hold for `n <= 5`:

- `n=3`: as `x+x` is exact (i.e. involves no rounding), so `(x+x)+x` only involves one rounding at the final step.
- `n=4` (and you're using the default rounding mode) then

  - if the last bit of `x` is 0, then `x+x+x` is exact, and so the results are equal by the same argument as `n=3`.
  - if the last 2 bits are `01`, then the exact value of `x+x+x` will have last 2 bits of `1|1` (where | indicates the final bit in the format), which will be rounded up to `0|0`. The next addition will give an exact result `|01`, so the result will be rounded down, cancelling out the previous error.
  - if the last 2 bits are `11`, then the exact value of `x+x+x` will have last 2 bits of `0|1`, which will be rounded down to `0|0`. The next addition will give an exact result `|11`, so the result will be rounded up, again cancelling out the previous error.
- `n=5` (again, assuming default rounding): since `x+x+x+x` is exact, it holds for the same reason as `n=3`.

For `n=6` it fails, e.g. take `x` to be `1.0000000000000002` (the next `double` after `1.0`), in which case `6x` is `6.000000000000002` and `x+x+x+x+x+x` is `6.000000000000001`

Comment: Wow your proof is much shorter than my proof by case analysis on whether 3*x is in the same binade as 2*x or 4*x.

Comment: From what I can tell based on exhaustive tests with IEEE-754 `binary32` (= `float`), multiplication by *n* is identical to *(n-1)* repeated additions when *n* ≤ 5 for `FE_TONEAREST`, *n*  ≤ 3 for `FE_TOWARDZERO`, *n* ≤ 3 for `FE_DOWNWARD`, and *n* ≤ 3 for `FE_UPWARD`. Is the proof extendable to directed rounding modes?

Comment: @njuffa The argument for n<=3 was independent of the choice of rounding mode. The proof became dependent on the rounding mode at the n=4 step.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Thanks for pointing that out, I had overlooked that the answer already addresses the issue of rounding mode.

Comment: It would be great if the answer would include the cases for non-default rounding modes mentioned by @njuffa.

Answer (score 3):

If `n` is for example `pow(2, 54)` then the multiplication will work just fine, but in the addition path once the result value is sufficiently larger than the input `x`, `result += x` will yield `result`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it doesn't hold generally. Multiplication by a number higher than 2 might not give the same results, as you have changed the exponent and can drop a bit if you replace with adds. Multiplication by two can't drop a bit if replaced by add operations, however.

Answer (score 1):

If the accumulator `result` in `case_add` becomes too large, adding `x` will introduce rounding errors. At a certain point, adding `x` won't have an effect at all. So the functions won't give the same result.

For example if `double x = 0x1.0000000000001p0` (hexadecimal float notation):

```
n  case_add              case_mul

1  0x1.0000000000001p+0  0x1.0000000000001p+0
2  0x1.0000000000001p+1  0x1.0000000000001p+1
3  0x1.8000000000002p+1  0x1.8000000000002p+1
4  0x1.0000000000001p+2  0x1.0000000000001p+2
5  0x1.4000000000001p+2  0x1.4000000000001p+2
6  0x1.8000000000001p+2  0x1.8000000000002p+2
```